# use re when reading csv file

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a list of keywords `healthy_list` that I want to check in a column of a csv file. If at least one keyword from the list shows up, then I write the entire row to a new csv file.

I'm using re.search for checking the keywords, then I record the row number and later use csv.writer for writing the new csv. But many rows containing the keywords do not show up in my new csv file. Any comments please?

```
healthy_new=[]
with open("Data 2017.csv","rb") as f:
    csvreader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    next(csvreader)
    for line, row in enumerate(csvreader):
        for word in healthy_list:
            try:
                if  (re.search(word,row[4].lower()) ):
                    healthy_new.append(line)
            except ValueError:
                continue 

healthy_new=list(set(healthy_new))

....

f = open("Data 2017.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)

data = open("healthy_new_output.csv", "w")
w = csv.writer(data, delimiter=',')
for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
    idx+=-1
    if idx in healthy_new:
        my_row = row
        w.writerow(my_row)
```

Edits:
some slices of Data 2017.csv 
[Data 2017.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mWAX.png)

healthy_list:

```
 [...'diet', 'low-fat', 'light', 'diet', 'salad', 'salads', 'baked', 'grilled', 'whole grain']
```

Comment: Can we get an example of `'Data 2017.csv'` and of `healthy_list`?

Comment: Why are you using `re` if you just want a string contain test?

Comment: `@Megalng` This is the only method I've learned so far... Which one do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to filter them out and then output it to csv using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` method if needed.

Below is the basic illustration about how it works:

Data 2017.csv

```
name,age,description
Andy,15,Having a bad stomach
Bobby,21,Having a good stomach and a little flu
Connie,22,Not having anything particularly bad
Derry,12,Bad stomach & lightheaded
```

The basic illustration of how this works:

```
In []: df = pd.read_csv('Data 2017.csv')

In []: word_flags = ['bad', 'flu', 'lightheaded']

In []: df_filtered = df.loc[:, :][df.description.str.contains("|".join(word_flags), re.IGNORECASE)]

In []: df_filtered
Out[]: 
     name  age                             description
0    Andy   15                    Having a bad stomach
1   Bobby   21  Having a good stomach and a little flu
2  Connie   22    Not having anything particularly bad
3   Derry   12               Bad stomach & lightheaded

In []: word_flags = ['flu', 'foo', 'bar']

In []: df_filtered = df.loc[:, :][df.description.str.contains("|".join(word_flags), re.IGNORECASE)]

In []: df_filtered
Out[]: 
    name  age                             description
1  Bobby   21  Having a good stomach and a little flu

df_filtered.to_csv("Filtered Data 2017.csv", index=False)
```

So now you have this:

```
name,age,description
Bobby,21,Having a good stomach and a little flu
```

To specifically address your problem, see the code passage below:

```
In []: word_flags = ['bad', 'flu', 'lightheaded']

In []: df2 = pd.DataFrame()

In []: for col in df.select_dtypes(object):
    ...:     df2 = pd.concat([df2, df[df[col].str.contains("|".join(word_flags), flags=re.IGNORECASE)]])
    ...:     

In []: df2
Out[]: 
     name  age                             description
0    Andy   15                    Having a bad stomach
1   Bobby   21  Having a good stomach and a little flu
2  Connie   22    Not having anything particularly bad
3   Derry   12               Bad stomach & lightheaded

In []: word_flags = ['flu', 'foo', 'bar']

In []: df2 = pd.DataFrame()

In []: for col in df.select_dtypes(object):
    ...:     df2 = pd.concat([df2, df[df[col].str.contains("|".join(word_flags), flags=re.IGNORECASE)]])
    ...:     

In []: df2
Out[]: 
    name  age                             description
1  Bobby   21  Having a good stomach and a little flu
```

However, this method only works well if you define the filter to only filter out a specific column. Let's say you define `word_flags` this way:

```
In []: word_flags = ['flu', 'foo', 'bar', 'bobby']
```

This will produce a duplicate record and need further cleaning.

```
In []: df2 = pd.DataFrame()

In []: for col in df.select_dtypes(object):
    ...:     df2 = pd.concat([df2, df[df[col].str.contains("|".join(word_flags), flags=re.IGNORECASE)]])
    ...:     

In []: df2
Out[]: 
    name  age                             description
1  Bobby   21  Having a good stomach and a little flu
1  Bobby   21  Having a good stomach and a little flu
```